# jQuery unrecognized expression error when giving color as a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple code which takes the value of the selected color and gives it as class. However there is this error when I select the elements with that variable class.

For example when the selected color is #65f678`$("."+window.eskirenkx).removeClass(window.eskirenkx).addClass(window.istenenrenk);`it gives me the error "unrecognized expression: .#65f678" but it also removes the class and adds the new class so I am very confused.

Thank you

EDIT: Found the answer via a friend. If anyone has the same problem just use \ at the beginning.

Comment: Could you simplify you code? (Or maybe even complete the code with the HTML and so). I don't understand what "eskirenkx" means.

Comment: window.eskirenkx is a hex color code. Comes from and ID of another element which is what I ment by selected color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addClass` accepts class name, but it appears as you are using color value for that. And that is wrong.

In order to achieve what you want you shall set corresponding CSS property instead:

```
$(".classname").css("background-color","#65f678");
```